# How to properly use semilogy?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

For class, we are supposed to calculate the absolute error, realistic error for an e series. In the end, we have to graph both the relative error and the absolute error using a "semilogy" graph. The code itself works fine and produces a numerical calculation as expected. But in terms of the graph, it doesn't get near the actual result.
Any idea of why this isn't working?
An image of the graph has been attached at the end.

```
import numpy as np
import math as m
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Exp_List = []
Relative_Error = []
Absolute_Error = []

def ExpCalc(x,N,t):
    exp = 0.0
    for i in range(N-1):
        fac = m.factorial(i)
        next_term = x**i/fac
        Exp_List.append(next_term)
        exp += next_term
        Relative = abs((sum(Exp_List)-t)/sum(Exp_List))
        Relative_Error.append(Relative)
        Absolute = abs(sum(Exp_List)-t)
        Absolute_Error.append(Absolute)
        i += 1

   return (Absolute_Error, Relative_Error)

A = m.exp(1)
B = m.exp(20)
C = m.exp(100)

print(ExpCalc(1,20,A))

plt.figure()
plt.semilogy(ExpCalc(1,20,A))
plt.show()
```

The image shows the numerical calculations as well as the graph obtained from the code

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
In particular, you haven't told us what you expected to see, and why that's the right answer.  Handing us a long list of floats and four straight lines doesn't describe the problem well enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the result of your `print(ExpCalc(1,20,A))` it is actually a tuple, which is causing the plotting behaviour you are seeing.

To fix this you can call the function and unpack the values, then do the plotting seperately to ensure you are plotting the correct values.

```
x, y = ExpCalc(1,20,A)

plt.figure()
plt.semilogy(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]